# How can I tell when I can run again?

Tags: red-faction-armageddon

I seem to run out of "sprint juice" in Red Faction and I'm not 100% sure how long I can run or when I can run again. Best I can tell there's no meter for it anywhere. Is there any visual/etc indication that shows me when I can sprint again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no indication of when you can run again.